# Java function getting results from a c++ code, Eclipse jni

Tags: java, android, c++, eclipse, java-native-interface

I am very new to Android and wanted to use a Java function which displays a value returned by a c++ function. my java code is:

```
btnCalculate.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                float bill = Float.parseFloat(txBill.getText().toString());
                float result = calculateCHARGE(bill);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),String.valueOf(result), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }

        }); 

    }
    public native float calculateCHARGE(float b);
    static
    {
        System.loadLibrary("MyBills");
    }

}
```

The cpp code is :

```
#include <jni.h>

extern "C"{
    JNIEXPORT jfloat JNICALL

    Java_com_example_mybills_MainActivity1_calculateCHARGE(JNIEnv* env,jobject thiz,jfloat bill)
    {
        jfloat answer = bill;

        return answer;
    }
```

Please help me.
I would also like to know how to display the "answer" on a textview I have on my graphical layout.

Comment: Help you with what, exactly?

Answer (score 1):

Have you downloaded Android NDK kit, it already have some basic example [Android NDK](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html)

if you are on Windows you have to setup CYGWIN in your machine, basic tutorial for NDK is here
http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/ndk-tutorial/